# Detecting USB device mapped in its own category

Tags: c#, usb, device-driver, device

I'm trying to programatically detect a National Instruments device that has been connected to my computer using USB. The code to detect all USB devices works fine. However, the National Instruments USB device is mapped as a category of its own (saw this from Device Manager). The category name is "NI-CAN Devices". The code to detect USB devices is given below. What must I change in order to detect the NI device?

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
            collection = searcher.Get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked using the class Win32_DeviceBus. All devices have been detected using this class.